# Start by displaying print-layout in VS10 Report Designer when running the form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, reporting-services, report-designer

When I run my report from VS10, I have to switch everytime to print-layout. Because I need to make 100+ small adjustment to my big table, I have to press the print-layout button everytime to see the result.

Is there a way, I can set it up, so I start by seeing the print-layout when running the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can adjust report viewer properties.  I found a adjustment that sets the zoom, in your case (print layout = whole page) so the default would need to be changed.

Here is the VB script for it from MS.

```
 'Declaration

 <CategoryAttribute("Appearance")> _
 <DefaultValueAttribute(ZoomMode.Percent)> _
 Public Property ZoomMode As ZoomMode

 'Usage

 Dim instance As ReportViewer
 Dim value As ZoomMode

 value = instance.ZoomMode

 instance.ZoomMode = value
```

I don't know if you have to use a # like value = 50 or if you can use value = Whole Page, it seems like the latter can be used since it bases the figures dimensions on the logical page to assume the view size.

Goood luck and check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.zoommode.aspx for further guidance and different code options.

Answer (score 2):

It´s an old post but found the exact answer. Setting Print-Layout instead of setting Zoom mode for the ReportViewer.

```
ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```